# Solid State Drive suddenly stopped working

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, formatting

I had SSD in my desktop and I had Windows 7 installed in it. Week age computer asked to restart to install the updates and I did. After that computer didn't boot. Finally I found that my SSD is not working. I tried to plug it to different computers and no luck. It even doesn't have any kind of ledthat indicates it is working. It still has warranty, but it has data that I don't want anyone else see it. Is there way to format it?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to see the Drive with a bootable format utility, but it only shows 8 MB. I formatted it and now it has 8MB space. I can hook it to working computer and copy some files in. I am still not sure if all my data is in there. I need to clean it before I return the SSD back.

Help appreciated!

Comment: which SSD do you use?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Intel SSD 320 Series 160 GB

Comment: do you use the latest firmware? https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=18363

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes I do have the latest.

Comment: you have the 8MB bug. Try this to repair the SSD: http://www.tested.com/forums/pc-and-mac/44240-huge-bug-in-intel-ssds-complete-recovery-information-here/ If this doesn't work, search for "intel ssd 320 series 8mb bug" and try the suggestions

Comment: @magicandre1981 I followed the steps and that fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer. Mark it as answer so that others see it faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have the 8MB bug. Try this to repair the SSD:

**Huge Bug in Intel SSDs: Complete Recovery Information Here**

http://www.tested.com/forums/pc-and-mac/44240-huge-bug-in-intel-ssds-complete-recovery-information-here/

> Restoring an Intel SSD affected by the 8MB bug:
>
> 1. Download and burn a bootable MHDD CD using the .iso file found here. (You can burn an .iso file using the built-in Windows 7 image
>      burning tool or with a free tool such as ImgBurn.)
> 2. Place the MHDD CD in your CD-ROM drive and boot your computer. You may have to change your boot order in the BIOS or press F12 during the
>      boot process to force your computer to boot from CD-ROM first.
> 3. When MHDD starts up it will ask you if you want to start with or without SCSI support. If this means nothing to you, then either option
>      will work.
> 4. MHDD will then display a list of drives installed on your system. Type in the number corresponding to the affected Intel drive and press
>      Enter.
> 5. A password must be set on the drive before you can restore it. Type "PWD" at the MHDD command prompt and enter something short and
>      memorable like "password". You will only need to remember this for the
>      duration of this process. Some BIOSes may lock the drive during the
>      boot process. If the PWD command fails, then unplug your SSD and plug
>      it back in once MHDD has started to avoid having it locked during
>      boot.
> 6. Type "FASTERASE", hit Enter, then enter the password you set in the previous step and hit Enter again. The word "BUSY" at the top of the
>      screen will flash for a bit. When it stops, the process is complete.
> 7. Press F2 to re-detect the drive information. If all has gone well, you should see the correct drive information now displayed at the top
>      of the screen.
> 8. Type "UNLOCK" and enter your password to unlock the drive, then "DISPWD" to clear the password permanently.
> 9. Remove the disc and reboot your computer. Your drive should now be back to its original from-the-factory state. Install your OS of choice
>      and so forth as usual.

Answer (score 0):

So when you say "I tried to plug it to different computers and no luck" what does that mean?

Was the secondary computer on or off when you connected the drive?

If you turn off the computer (the secondary computer you are using to test the drive), connect the drive, turn the computer back on - before the computer starts up press whatever key you need to in order to get BIOS to load (try F2, F8, F11, F10, F12, Esc, Del, Insert - it will be one of those).  Go to the part of the BIOS where it lists hard drives - do you see your SSD?   If it does not show up in BIOS there will not be any way to format the drive.

Comment: I tried that. I can see the SSD in the BIOS. How can I format it?

Comment: When I plugged it into a different computer as a secondary drive nothing happens. I can't see the hard drive on my drives list. I can see it only in BIOS.